# 100% stage completion in a single run

Tags: yoshis-woolly-world

Yoshi's Woolly World is a bit more forgiving than Yoshi's Island, in that you can achieve 100% completion of a stage and a corresponding star on the map over multiple runs, rather than having to collect everything in a single attempt.

However, if you *do* grab everything in a single shot (20 hearts, 5 flowers, 5 yarn balls and 20 stamp patches), you get a pink flower doodle over the results screen like in the original game.

Do these "one-run 100%" results count towards anything or get listed anywhere, or is it just a nod to the original game?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, those achievements don't count for anything else. Just for a good feeling for you. I have some of them too and haven't mentioned anything besides the good feeling in my belly to achieved it. :-D